Action (of a graded monoid) required
Reference request: Did the construction below appear anywhere before? Any mentions of it or especially any links to something commonly known would be really helpful. I feel that it might be related to operads, but I can not figure out the details. See also the question below.
Construction: Everything below can be easily adapted to rings/algebras, but we describe it for monoids. Let $M=\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} M_p$ be a graded monoid ($M_p$ are sets). Let $N$ be another graded monoid $N=\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0}N_p$. Then $\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} M_p\times N_p$ is a graded monoid again and suppose we have a homomorphism of graded monoids
\begin{equation}
\varphi:\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} M_p\times N_p\longrightarrow \bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} N_p
\end{equation}
Explicitly this means that for any $p\geq 0$ we have a map $\varphi_p:M_p\times N_p\longrightarrow N_p$, which satisfies the following property
$$
\varphi_{p_1+p_2}(m_1m_2,n_1n_2)=\varphi_{p_1}(m_1,n_1)\varphi_{p_2}(m_2,n_2),
$$
for $m_1\in M_{p_1}$, $n_1\in N_{p_1}$, $m_2\in M_{p_2}$, and $n_2\in N_{p_2}$, where on the left hand-side $m_1m_2$ and $n_1n_2$ mean products of elements in the corresponding monoids as well as on the right hand-side we have a product of two $\varphi$'s which is understood as the product of elements of $N$.
Question: It is very desirable to treat this $\varphi$ as an action of something related to $M$ on something related to $N$. In the example below this is almost done, except the fact that there each graded component $\varphi_p$ is an action map, and I wish to recast this in terms of $M$ and $N$ themselves, but not their graded components. In the best-case scenario, I want to find a (known) action-like structure whose definition is exactly given by the construction above. It might sound like ''a graded monoid $M$ acts on a graded monoid $N$ in the sense of something, if there is a homomorphism $\varphi$ ...''.
Example: Take $M_p=S(p)$ the symmetric group and $N_p=V^{\otimes p}$ the $p$-th tensor power of a vector space $V$. Then $M$ is a monoid with respect to “concatenation” of permutations $S(p)\times S(q)\longrightarrow S(p+q)$, $(\sigma,\tau)\mapsto \sigma\times\tau$, where $\sigma\times\tau$ permutes the first $p$ elements as $\sigma$ and the last $q$ elements as $\tau$. And $N$ is a monoid with respect to the tensor product. Then each $\varphi_p$ is just the usual action of the symmetric group by permutations of tensors
$$
(\sigma,v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_p)\mapsto (v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(p)})
$$
for $\sigma\in S(p)$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_p\in V$.
Cross-posted at MathOverflow

What do you mean you want to recast this in terms of $M$ and $N$ themselves? Is the grading on $M$ not a part of $M$? Regardless, you're right that this construction has been studied before. A graded monoid in $\mathcal{V}$ (For $\mathcal{V}$=Sets, Abelian groups, Vector spaces, these are respectively graded monoids, rings, and algebras) is "just" a monoid object in the category of graded $\mathcal{V}$-objects. And what you've described is the usual action of one monoid on another in this category. See here, for instance

If you can clarify exactly what you're looking for with the "in terms of $M$ and $N$ themselves" comment, I might be able to give a more helpful answer. For instance, what would you like to happen in the example you've given?

@ChrisGrossack thanks! Probably action of a monoid on another monoid is exactly what I need, but I couldn’t find the definition in this link. I was thinking about splitting the construction in the post into several commonly known parts each of which can be written without using the graded components. So, all the manipulations with graded components should be hidden inside these part. This is what I meant by this vague formulation. But it’s even better, if the construction fits a general definition.
